# How to get lowest location of controls in array using linq

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

how to get lowest location of controls in array using linq

i have array of controls say 
dim oClipboard() as control

i needed the control which has lowest location or minimum location value from tha oclipboard

so far i have tried linq with min function

```
Dim p = c.Select(Function(g) g.Location).Min.ToString
Dim x = c.Select(Function(g) g).Min(Function(h) h.Location)
```

both of above give me error stated below

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
HResult=-2147024809
Message=At least one object must implement IComparable.
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
at System.Collections.Comparer.Compare(Object a, Object b)
at System.Collections.Generic.ObjectComparer`1.Compare(T x, T y)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Min[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Min[TSource,TResult](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 selector)
```

is there any way i could get control whhich has lowest location

Comment: What do you mean by *lowest location*? The location is defined by 2 coordinates: X and Y. So please define more precisely which control you would like to find - the one that's located left-most, or bottom-most, or some combination of those 2?

Comment: i know this is ugly question but i needed nearest to (0,0) or atleast lowest y value

Comment: What do you mean by a control?  Why are you using the clipboard?

Comment: its an array of multiple controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by *lowest location* you mean the control which has shortest Euclidean distance to the (0,0) point you could use the [`Aggregate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method:

```
Control[] oClipboard = ...;
Control control = oClipboard.Aggregate((curMin, c) => (curMin == null || Math.Sqrt(c.Location.X * c.Location.X + c.Location.Y * c.Location.Y) < Math.Sqrt(curMin.Location.X * curMin.Location.X + curMin.Location.Y * curMin.Location.Y) ? c : curMin));
```

or if you just want to find the control with smallest Y coordinate:

```
Control control = oClipboard.Aggregate((curMin, c) => (curMin == null || c.Location.Y < curMin.Location.Y ? c : curMin));
```

Now all that's left for you as an exercise is to translate this to VB.NET.

Comment: it seems to be working for me but will please explain in english what you have so that i can understand the same

Comment: hello will somebody please explain what is above code  as i am new to linq

Comment: The Aggregate extension method takes 2 parameters: The current candidate element for some condition and the current element being iterated. It's your responsibility to compare those 2 and decide which one of them to return by applying the desired function. In my example I calculate the Euclidean distances to the (0,0) point between the current candidate (`curMin`) and the current element (`c`) and return the current element if it has shorter distance, otherwise I return the current minimum.

Answer (score 1):

A `Point` doesn't implement `IComparable`. How do you want to compare two points?

You could provide a custom `IEqualityComparer<Point>` and pass an instance to `Min` or `Max`. If you are only interested in the [`X`-Coordinate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.x(v=vs.110).aspx) for example you could also use this:

```
Dim pxMin As Int32 = c.Select(Function(g) g.Location.X).Min()
```

If you want the control you can use this approach using an anonymous type:

```
Dim controlPoints = From c in Me.Controls.Cast(Of Control)() 
                    Select controlLoc = New With { .Control = c, .Location = c.Location }
                    Order by controlLoc.Location.X , controlLoc.Location.Y 
Dim minLocControl As Control = controlPoints.First().Control
```

If you want to handle the case that two controls could have overlapping locations:

```
Dim orderedControlPointGroups =
    From c In Me.Controls.Cast(Of Control)()
    Order By c.Location.X, c.Location.Y
    Group By c.Location Into controlGroups = Group

Dim minLocControlGroup = orderedControlPointGroups.First()
Dim minLocation as Point = minLocControlGroup.Location 
Dim allMinControls as IEnumerable(of Control) = minLocControlGroup.controlGroups
```

Comment: it gives me point i need the control in retrun or its name in return

Comment: the solution is case of two controls is giving me logical error as only 2 buttons are on same location and (`allMinControls`)  gives length of 3 in which one of 2 controls is repeated

Comment: @dandy: i cannot reproduce it. tested it with 4 buttons where two are on the same location. Only those two are in `allMinControls `